# Installing ROS on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any clear issues I should be aware of when installing ROS on Ubuntu 13.04 from source?  I followed the instructions but am having issues installing the packages, specifically the two following packages:

E: Unable to locate package python-rosdep
E: Unable to locate package python-wstool

Could someone please help?

Should I downgrade to 12.10?  Is that a better idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62544/installing-ros-on-ubuntu-13.04/) by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Souldier](https://answers.ros.org/users/4820/souldier/) on 2013-05-13**:
I know a couple of days ago I read a question where another user was having issues with 13.04 (http://answers.ros.org/question/62467/publisher-sleeping-forever/) -- Obviously, this won't help you in any way other than to let you know that others are experiencing problems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only ROS Hydro supports Ubuntu Raring, and that is still in alpha test. What version of ROS are you trying to install?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0